# Reveal all outlook email passwords on windows 2k8 server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-server-2008

Is there anyway I can find out all the outlook email passwords on our server? It has windows server 2008. I've tried various programs, but none of them seem to work. It also has outlook 2010.

Comment: Who are you and what are you doing on somebody's server??

Comment: it's my server, and i need to find out one of the users outlook passwords. The thing is, i don't want to delete his password and enter his account and do it that way

Comment: @CalvT It's a sign of poor security that you can "find out" a password.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a password being set on an account using Active Directory, it is possible (and easy) to reset the password for the user, as the following shows:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782255(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: but that;s what i don't want to do

Comment: If you're using Exchange Server then just give yourself permissions to the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the PST file you need to access then [Mail PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mailpv.html) would do it. Otherwise, if it's the password on the server I think you need to change the password, that's the whole point of the security.